# Api acl check permission not working for guest user

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, web-services, acl

Hi I have added api acl for guest user vy adding tag

```
<privileges>
    <admin>
        <create>1</create>
        <retrieve>1</retrieve>
        <update>1</update>
        <delete>1</delete>
    </admin>
    <guest>
        <create>1</create>
        <retrieve>1</retrieve>
        <update>1</update>
        <delete>1</delete>
    </guest>
</privileges>
```

but guest user get collection every time. if i configure from `admin > system > Webservices > roles` and unchack from category menu still got the same response.

Expected:

- if uncheck from roles than need to empty responce or access denied message.

Can any one have idea how to solve this issue.